# Should edits update old answers with changed data by adding a section

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Recently in the review queue I came across:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4502376

I wasn't sure what to put so left it a while, when I came back it had completed review - with 3 reject and 2 approve votes.

The change was clearly an attempt to improve the answer and update it with better information, but it was also a large change to the answer. Clearly I'm not the only one with mixed feelings as we had a nearly perfect split on the votes?

What was the "correct" case here? My first thought was that it should be posted as a new answer with a comment on the old one but I don't know if that's the usual approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rejecting was the correct action here, because the edit is actually meant as a comment to the answer. Commenting would be better than suggesting an edit, but the editor suggested an edit because he doesn't have enough rep for commenting.